# equivalent to having, lag or similar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My aim is selecting the rows in which the sum of the column “value” is >1000, considering the cumulative value for each month. For instance client1 reaches that value in month 3, since the sum of value during the first 3 months is 1160, as shown in the target_data.
My hints were about playing with group by, I was wondering about also using filter or shift, but I am stacked. In "target_data" I show the desidered result

```
raw_data = {'client': ['client1','client1','client1','client1','client2','client2','client2','client2','client2'],
'month': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5],
'value': [10,350,800,400,300,300,300,300,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['client','month','value'])
df

target_data = {'client': ['client1','client2'],
'month': [3,4],
'value': [800,300],
'cumulative': [1160,1200]}


df2 = pd.DataFrame(target_data, columns = ['client','month','value','cumulative'])

df2


df_grouped = df.groupby(['client'])['value'].sum().reset_index(name='sum_value')


df_grouped.loc[df_grouped['sum_value'] > 1000]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) here to create a `Series` of cumulative sums. Then use [`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) (greater than) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the first index where the condition is met, we'll use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter to these indices and finally assign the cumulative sum back in with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s_cum = df.groupby('client')['value'].cumsum() 
df.loc[s_cum.gt(1000).groupby(df['client']).idxmax()].assign(cumulative=s_cum)
```

[out]

```
    client  month  value  cumulative
2  client1      3    800        1160
7  client2      4    300        1200
```